# Having an error - Cannot convert value of type 'Season' to expected argument type '[Fruit]'

Tags: swift, swiftui

My problem is that when I click on a specific item in a ListView I want it to send me to a different file on my SwiftUI project. I get an error - `Cannot convert value of type 'Season' to expected argument type '[Fruit]'`. You can see where the error is with a comment in my code. Here's my code:

```
//
//  SideMenuView.swift
//  Fruity
//
//  Created by Hristo on 25.11.23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct SideMenuView: View {
  
    var fruits: [Fruit] = fruitsData
    var seasons: [Season] = seasonData
    @AppStorage("isContent") var isContent: Bool?
    
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Choose a season of your choice:")
            .fontWeight(.bold)
        .font(.title)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
      
      Divider()
        .frame(width: 300, height: 2)
        .background(Color.black)
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
      
      // MARK: - Content
      
        List {
            ForEach(seasons[0...3]) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView1(fruits: item)) { // The error is here !!!
                    SeasonRowView(seasons: item)
                        .padding(.vertical, 4)
                }
            }
        }
      .font(.title)
      
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding(32)
    .background(Color.white)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
  }
  
}

#Preview {
    SideMenuView(fruits: fruitsData, seasons: seasonData)
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
        
    @State private var isShowingSettings: Bool = false
    @State private var showMenu: Bool = false
    @AppStorage("isContent") var isContent: Bool?
    
    var fruits: [Fruit] = fruitsData
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(fruits[0...3]) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: FruitDetailView(fruit: item)) {
                        FruitRowView(fruit: item)
                            .padding(.vertical, 4)
                    }
                }
            }
      // Some useless code for this situation...
    }
```

Here is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/HristoMihovski/Fruity

I tried surfing on the net, but no luck. I tried to try different combinations of code that pop in my head - no luck. Please don't critisice me, because I'm 13 years old and I'm new to programming - 6 months. Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to pass a `Season` to `ContentView1`, which expects `[Fruit]`. It's not clear what your intention is with `ContentView1`, but maybe you mean to have a `View` that shows a `Season` instead here? Or, instead of passing `item` to it, pass `fruits`.

Comment: My intention is when you click on of the items on the `ListView` it will show the `ContentView1` and you will see it and all it's content. By the way I tried `fruits` instead of `item` - no result.

Comment: `Season` and `Fruit` are just name of the variables from my database. If you want I can show it.

Comment: `ContentView1` expects you to pass `[Fruit]`, not `Season` -- like I said, you have to pass `[Fruit]`. You are trying to pass `Season`. But, it's not clear what you are trying to show in `ContentView1`, which you haven't included. Should it show a bunch of `Fruit`? If so, the parameter makes sense. Should it show a `Season`? If so, you need to change it's parameters to accept a `Season`

Comment: I want it to include a bunch of `Fruit`. Now I'll edit it and show you the `ContentView1`.

Comment: `ContentView1(fruits: fruits)`

Comment: I added the ContentView1. I tried `ContentView1(fruits: fruits)` but when I click one of the items in the `ListView` nothing happends again. =(

Comment: "Nothing happens" is different than the compilation error that you're experiencing in the question. If nothing happens, perhaps you don't have a `NavigationStack`. Also, you didn't add `ContentView1`, you added `ContentView`. Maybe your views are the same and your naming is confusing you?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @jnpdx
With the `NavigationStack` everything is work is normally now. I will name my title of the Stack Overflow question better.

Comment: The title of your post is fine. I was suggesting that you might want to have more descriptive/different names than `ContentView` and `ContentView1` since you got them mixed up here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple issues here

1. You are trying to pass `item` which is a `Season` to an initializer that expects `fruits` which is `[Fruit]`.
2. You don't have a `NavigationStack` or `NavigationSplitView`, in order for the view to be pushed, you need a navigation to wrap all the stack.
3. Consider cleaning up your code, this includes:

   1. Naming conventions
   2. Merge `List` and `ForEach`
   3. Also, avoid using indices like this. Thanks to @jnpdx.

      ***You can do something like:***

```swift
List(fruits.prefix(4)) { item in
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Using indices like this in SwiftUI is discouraged. Check out "Demystify SwiftUI" from WWDC

Comment: Of course, thanks @jnpdx, edited my answer.

Comment: Great -- now you can remove the `id: \.self`, since `Fruit` is `Identifiable`

Comment: Thanks @PiereJanineh and @jnpdx! This is working now and my hamburger menu is doing it's job as like it to do. This will help me a lot with my project that I want to post on the Apple store in the start of 2024. Here's my GitHub repo if you want check _all my code_: 
https://github.com/HristoMihovski/Fruity

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about the intent of your code and sorry for not being able to provide the best solution in the current state. The issue seems to arise from trying to pass data to fruits, which already has fruitsData assigned and you are trying to pass an object of type Season where an array of Fruit objects is expected. Based on the code you've provided, you could try the following approach:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
        
    @State private var isShowingSettings: Bool = false
    @State private var showMenu: Bool = false
    @AppStorage("isContent") var isContent: Bool?
    
    var fruits: [String] // Remove the assignment and input the type you desire.
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(fruits[0...3]) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: FruitDetailView(fruit: item)) {
                        FruitRowView(fruit: item)
                            .padding(.vertical, 4)
                    }
                }
            }
      // Some useless code for this situation...
    }
```

It seems like you are using a model and viewModel. In such cases, consider using property wrappers like StateObject, EnvironmentObject, or ObservedObject in your viewModel to reference published data. This could be a good approach to consider. I wish you luck and hope your issue gets resolved.

Comment: Thanks @HarrisonCho that you tried to help, but I don't need to change anything in the `ContentView`. I gave it because it was almost ideantical with the `SideMenuView` and the logic is the same and something breaks in the `SideMenuView` (as I explained up in the comments and in the question). Thanks again! =D